# How does an array boolean correlate a Char entry to true or false?

Tags: c, char, boolean

I am using a Boolean array to check if a Char has been seen by a character occurrence check program.

My question is: How/why does/can an array boolean correlate a Char entry to true or false?

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 char c = text[i];
 if (seen[c]==true) {
  continue;
 }
seen[c]=true;
```

Below is code snippet that includes the 'bool' in question. Note the use of bool works here, want to know why/how.

```
char* text = lower_case_all();

bool seen[256];
int i;
char c;
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
 seen[i]=false;
}

int len = strlen(text);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  char c = text[i];
  if (seen[c]==true) {
    continue;
  }
  seen[c]=true;
  int occs = compute_occ(c, text);
  if (occs>0) {
    printf("%c : %d : ",c, occs );
 }
}
```

Comment: `c` is used as an index into an array of flags indicating whether the value of `c` was ever seen in prior processing. This restricts invoking `compute_occ` to only once per any occurrence of any given value of `c`. Equating `char` with `bool` has *nothing* to do with that algorithm (which, incidentally, is rife with undefined behavior if you ever get values not in `0x00..0x7F` in `c`, and `char` is signed on your platform, as it is on most).

Comment: Aside: `bool seen[256];   ....   if (seen[c]==true) {` is [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions).  Consider coding `if (seen[c]) {`.  It may help make code clearer.

Comment: With `char c`, `c` is used as an index into array `seen[]`.  Unfortunately, `c` may be negative and then `seen[c]` is undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: The thing that puzzles me is this: *"I am using a Boolean array to check if a Char has been seen by a character occurrence check program."* - If *you* wrote this, how can you not understand and answer your own question? Surly you know why you wrote your code the way you did, right?

Answer (score 0):

C Characters are switched into their ASIC number equivalents when used as an index for an array.